# Duration (Year Conversion)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am new in Redshift. How do I convert to years/months.

Year(Varchar): 1 year 6 months.

Expected Result(Integer): 1.5

Comment: `1 year 6 months` Can you expand on what that data is? is it a single column? is it varchar? is it 2 columns? are these numbers? what are some other examples

Comment: Could you please provide more information and detail in your question. I.e. what the raw data looks like , what have you tried already etc.

Comment: these are the other records from duration field ----  1 year 6 months, 9 months, 2 years. I tried split function, so that I can separate numbers and words before converting it to years.   Single Column (VARCHAR)

Comment: So you are saying that this is is coming in as pure text, generated by some external system? Can you provide more examples, such as how it look with partial months, and less than 1 year? (Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding this is similar to the one which I answered in a different SO question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47277430/3259044