# Convert Varchar to Float/double

Tags: sql, converters, amazon-redshift

I have column 'Age' (Varchar)
How can I select query and convert it to (float)

**Pet_Name**         **Age(varchar)**
John                  2 years 6 months.
Anne                  3 years and 6 months.

*output:*
**Pet_Name**         **Age(float/double)**
John                  *2.5*
Anne                 3.5

my problem is that the inputs does not follow a specific date/age format and was entered as string.

Comment: is it ALWAYS "*n years and n months.*" could it be "23 yrs" " 6 mnths" is it always English? you need more examples. Every exception makes this harder, even the number of spaces might make a difference. & If you intend to fix this i hope the new "Age" column is a decimal , not a string.

Comment: 2.5 is not an integer. it's float or double

Comment: change the title to your question, integer cannot have a decimal portion

Comment: I updated above question from int to float.

Comment: @Used_By_Already my problem is that the inputs does not follow a specific date/age format and was entered as string.

Comment: yes, I understand that, but you haven't actually answered ALL the items I raised. there is no point in writing code that will convert one row only, easier to do that manually.... you need ot consider our question in much more depth

Comment: If it's came 6 Years and 4 months. What result you need?

Comment: @DineshDB 6.3....

Comment: Can you you give all the ranges?

Comment: @Mark What would the string be for merely 3 months? What would it be for 15 days? How is the string created -- is it typed manually, or generated by a system? More info please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the age column always has two numbers, I have used **[REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html)** function in Redshift to write below answer:

```
create temp table pets (petname varchar(10), age varchar(20));

insert into pets values ('john','2 years 6 mnths');
insert into pets values ('anne','3 Years and 4 months');
insert into pets values ('buddy','4 yrs and 3 Mnths');
insert into pets values ('tommy','9 Years and 5 mnths');
insert into pets values ('alex','5 YEARS and 12 mnts');
insert into pets values ('bob','0 year and 7 Mnts');
insert into pets values ('danny','10 years 11 mnths');
insert into pets values ('sunny','81 years 10 mnths');


select petname,(REGEXP_SUBSTR(AGE,'[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]',1))::integer+(REGEXP_SUBSTR(AGE,'[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]',3))/12 as age from pets;

+--------------------+
|petname   | age     | 
+--------------------+
|john      |2.5000   |
|sunny     |81.8333  |
|danny     |10.9166  |
|anne      |3.3333   |
|alex      |6.0000   |
|tommy     |9.4166   |
|bob       |0.5833   |
|buddy     |4.2500   |
+--------------------+
```

**Note:** The above answer works only when there are two numbers in the *age* column.

Comment: What if the input is merely `3 months`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein hmmm.. As I mentioned in the answer this works only when the column has two numbers. I have updated the answer with a note now.